# Using ServiceStack.Text as JSON Serializer for SignalR

Tags: json, signalr

To have consistent serialization across my application layers, I want to use the same Serialization library (ServiceStack.Text) for SignalR that I use everywhere else.

While following SignalR's Wiki [entry](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Extensibility#replacing-the-ijsonserializer) for replacing the used JSON Serializer, I created this basic handler:

```
public class SignalrServiceStackJsonSerializer : IJsonSerializer
{
    public void Serialize(object value, TextWriter writer)
    {
        var selfSerializer = value as IJsonWritable;
        if (selfSerializer != null)
            selfSerializer.WriteJson(writer);
        else
            JsonSerializer.SerializeToWriter(value, writer);
    }

    public object Parse(TextReader reader, Type targetType)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromReader(reader, targetType);
    }
}
```

Integration:

```
var serializer = new SignalrServiceStackJsonSerializer();
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IJsonSerializer), () => serializer);
```

Unfortunately, after integrating it, the SignalR JS client does get different packages than with the default serializer. As it looks like, the default serializer generates (at least for non-user messages) JSON with properties capped to 1 character, which does not occur after replacing it with ServiceStack.Text. Thus, SignalR tries to access 'I' but it received 'Id'. I was unable to find the respective parts of the SignalR server-side sourcecode.

Did I do something wrong or do I have to create a more complex wrapper to use ServiceStack.Text as a JSON serializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bother trying. We have a deep dependency on JSON.NET and we've even removed this extensibility in the next release. Sorry.

Comment: well that sucks ;) but thanks for clearing that up, will have to see how I work around the differences in ServiceStack.Text and JSON.Net.

Comment: Hum.. it's not a good news. I guess I have to include both serializer in my app.

Comment: Why is MS using an inferior JSON SLOW JSON serializer? ServiceStack.Text, Jil, and FastJSON beat it to death.

Comment: This is terrible news.