# How to send pre serialized json through hub API method

Tags: serialization, signalr, servicestack

For performance reasons , i want to use servicestack JSON serializer instead of default JSON.Net. It seems there is no way to replace serializer in signalR2 and is not even recommended as the link says.[custom serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215640/using-servicestack-text-as-json-serializer-for-signalr)
 what if i run my custom serializer on my object and pass the generated json string ?

```
string stringOutput = ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(tick);
Clients.All.hello(stringOutput);
```

will signalR skip serialization altogether?. Is there any better way to use custom serializer with signalR?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is currently impossible, reading their open github issue:
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1546 (now open unassigned 20 days ago)